# What could be the output for these codes?

Tags: modulo

I was doing some exercises and this question came out? Im unsure whats the output as it kinda confuse me. I need some help. I thought it was 9 but then, got it wrong.

```
Int x = 15 
Int y = 6

X %= y
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is c language, it's should be 3.

`a%=b` means `a=a%b`

Mod operation `a=b%c` means `a=b-x*c` where `x` is the integer part of `b/c`.

Comment: Can u explain why?

Comment: Mod operation `a=b%c` means `a=b-x*c` where `x` is the integer part of `b/c`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3.

x %= y is equivalent to x = x % y.

Thus here X = 15 % 6 which is 3. (9 is not in the range [0; 5])